# split textarea lines that starts with "-" regex jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, split

i am trying to split each textarea line that starts with "-" or "- " or " -" into individual span element with specific ID 1,2,3,4 etc..

The closest regex code i found is `^-.+` but it wont work for me like it works on:

https://regex101.com/r/yCOvyR/4

My current code is available also here: http://jsfiddle.net/ribosed/468emjct/59/

Thanks for any help.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#txt").keyup(function() {
    entered = $('#txt').val()
    lines = entered.split(/\n/);

    spans = "";
    for (var i in lines) {
      spans += "<span style='color:red;'>- " + lines[i] + "</span><br/>";
    }

    $(".res").html(spans);
  });
});
```

```css
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.col {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->
  <!-- Option 1: jQuery and Bootstrap Bundle (includes Popper) -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!-- 
  Bootstrap docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs
-->

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <form>
          <textarea id="txt" rows="5" cols="60" placeholder="Type something here..."></textarea>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 res"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

plit and match proces should be achieved while user type in textarea. I tried to use .keyup()

Comment: `lines = entered.split("\n").filter(x => x.trim().charAt(0) == "-");`

Comment: There's no regex in your fiddle / code snippet

Comment: Wiktor Stribižew, thanks for help, can you update your code so that span value collect everitnig until next "-"  like:   `- first line test  
rest of the first line (shis line should be in first line/span value)
- second line`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not checking the Regex in your code, so it's out of question to ask "why" it's not working.

I think this should work:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  const regex = /^\s*-\s*/;
  $("#txt").keyup(function() {
    const entered = $('#txt').val()
    const lines = entered.split(/\n/);

    let spans = "";
    for (const line of lines) {
      if (regex.test(line)) {
        spans += "<span style='color:red;'>- " + line.replace(regex, '') + "</span><br/>";
      }
    }

    $(".res").html(spans);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <form>
        <textarea id="txt" rows="5" cols="60" placeholder="Type something here..."></textarea>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 res"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Technophyle, can you change the regex only to split if line starts with "-" or " -"  not on every newline in textarea, thanks!

Comment: Updated. Next time, show us more of your efforts. This is not a free outsourcing service.

Comment: if second line doesnt start its content should be inside previous match   `- first line  (first match)
second line (rest of first match because it does not starts with "-"
- third line (second match span)` , but thanx for this!   i really tried to search first, but i am tired of searching, i understand what you are saying, THANK YOU FOR YOUR TIME!

Comment: looks like this updated version is not working at all "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression flags" ..

Comment: Works for me when I run it here.

Comment: Its ok, my bad :( i tried few times withoud "-" trigger :)), sorry for interruption!